# How to ignore http requests health check in kubernetes within liveness probe / readiness probe?

Tags: kubernetes, http-headers, marathon

I am working on migrating one of the application to kubernetes. I want to discard the result if the health check returns http(100-199).

Similar to one which we have in marathon

> IgnoreHttp1xx (Optional. Default: false): Ignore HTTP informational
>   status codes 100 to 199. If the HTTP health check returns one of
>   these, the result is discarded and the health status of the task
>   remains unchanged.

How can i achieve this in kubernetes? Does it accept if i pass like this?

```
  livenessProbe:
    httpGet:
      path: /v1/health
      port: 9102
      scheme: HTTP
      httpHeaders:
       - name: ignoreHttp1xx
         value: false
```

Unfortunately i have no way to test this in our environment. Does it ignore such requests? If not what is the alternative i can use for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Any code greater than or equal to 200 and less than 400 indicates
>   success. Any other code indicates failure. You can see the source code
>   for the server in server.go.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-probes/#configure-probes

Maybe you can change your healthcheck to return something between 200-300 when it is going to return 100-199 , kind of overwirte.